# My javascript function only runs when there is a breakpoint in the browser debugger?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, javascript-debugger

I am working with ArcGIS Javascript and have a layer of graphics on a map. When a user slides the 'opacity' range slider, it calls a changeOpacity function that in turn calls 2 functions:

1) openModal function - puts a loading gif over top of the map.

2) renderMapOpacity function - re-renders the graphics on the map to be the specified opacity. This function also closes the loading gif.

When normally running, the first function loadingGif is skipped and only the second one happens.

However, if I step through the javascript code using the chrome debugger, everything works as planned.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

The renderMapOpacity function can take a considerable amount of time, so I wanted a loading gif to appear while it processes the data.

Here is some of the related code:

HTML of slider:

```
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" style="width:100%" onchange="MapLibrary.changeOpacity(this.form.id, this.value)" id="slider" />
```

Javascript:

```
changeOpacity: function (viewNum, Opacity) {

    if (Opacity == 1) {
        submitForm(viewNum);
    }
    else {
        openModal(viewNum.slice(-1));
        renderMapOpacity((viewNum.slice(-1)), Opacity);
    }
}
```

Some notes about the `submitForm` function, this renders the map at regular opacity. The `submitForm` button calls `openModal` as well so it is not needed in the if statement. Specifically, the `submitForm` function calls `openModal`, then sends an XHR request to a controller and then calls a function called `renderMap` (similar to `renderMapOpacity`, it renders graphics and also closes the loading gif at the end). And this method works to open and close the loading gif oddly.

A note about the `renderMapOpacity` function, it requires approx. 10 seconds to finish, so there would be plenty of time to see the loading gif spin.

Comment: If you make multiple changes to the DOM, you don't see the intermediate steps, only the final result (unless you use transitions or animation).

Comment: You can put a `setTimeout()` for `renderMapOpacity()` to keep the loading gif up longer. Your script is making it appear, but you don't see it because it goes away in a few milliseconds.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason since the renderMapOpacity function requires approx. 10 seconds to finish, so it shouldn't go away in milliseconds. Also, I'm not familiar with what the DOM is.